# reactstrap Collapse does not have any formating, and neither does card

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, reactstrap

Reactstraps cards and collapse does not seem to work. I don't know what I am doing wrong but I have tried a few different methods to no avail. The text just sits there and the button does nothing.

I have tried reactstrap, react bootstrap and the normal html code. I am using rekit ide to work on this project.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Collapse, Button, CardBody, Card } from 'reactstrap';

class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
this.state = { collapse: false };
  }

  toggle() {
this.setState(state => ({ collapse: !state.collapse }));
  }

  render() {
return (
  <div>
    <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle} style={{ marginBottom: '1rem' }}>Toggle</Button>
    <Collapse isOpen={this.state.collapse}>
      <Card>
        <CardBody>
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit,
         enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil
         anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred
         nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    </Collapse>
  </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

I should get a collapsing card when I push the button, but I get nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install bootstrap

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

and import it in `src/index.js` file following [Installation Guide](https://reactstrap.github.io/) like below:

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```